# Sql statement on large data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that brings back chunks of data using some between logic. The PostFamilyTags table in my statement has has about 1.5 million rows. The sql statement below runs very slow.

```
SELECT TOP(100)*  FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(ORDER BY p.date  DESC) as NUM,    
        m.postfamilymediaID, 
        m.postfamilyID, 
        p.blogID,
        p.userID, 
        p.BlogPostID, 
        m.postfamilymediatypeID as Type, 
        p.Title, 
        m.Address, 
        m.AddressEncoded, 
        m.ThumbNailAddress, 
        p.Date, 
        p.Summary, 
        p.Url, 
        m.ThumbNailIndex, 
        m.ThumbNailHeight, 
        m.ThumbNailWidth, 
        m.ThumbNailHeightAlt, 
        m.ThumbNailWidthAlt, 
        m.ItemName, 
        m.id3Title, 
        m.id3SubTitle, 
        m.id3ContributingArtists, 
        m.id3AlbumArtist, 
        m.id3Album, 
        m.id3Year, 
        m.id3Genre, 
        m.id3Length, 
        m.IsPublic      
FROM         
        PostFamilyMedia as m
        inner join 
        PostFamily as p on m.postfamilyID = p.postfamilyID 
        inner join 
        PostFamilyTags as pt on p.postfamilyID = pt.postfamilyID 
        inner join --Tags
        Tags as t on pt.tagID = t.tagID 
        Where t.TagLevel = 1 and t.Tag = 'Electronic' 
) AS a  WHERE NUM >= (100 + 1)  AND NUM <= (100 + 100)
```

But When I take the between logic out, it works great.

```
SELECT TOP(100)
        m.postfamilymediaID, 
        m.postfamilyID, 
        p.blogID,
        p.userID, 
        p.BlogPostID, 
        m.postfamilymediatypeID as Type, 
        p.Title, 
        m.Address, 
        m.AddressEncoded, 
        m.ThumbNailAddress, 
        p.Date, 
        p.Summary, 
        p.Url, 
        m.ThumbNailIndex, 
        m.ThumbNailHeight, 
        m.ThumbNailWidth, 
        m.ThumbNailHeightAlt, 
        m.ThumbNailWidthAlt, 
        m.ItemName, 
        m.id3Title, 
        m.id3SubTitle, 
        m.id3ContributingArtists, 
        m.id3AlbumArtist, 
        m.id3Album, 
        m.id3Year, 
        m.id3Genre, 
        m.id3Length, 
        m.IsPublic      
FROM         
        PostFamilyMedia as m
        inner join 
        PostFamily as p on m.postfamilyID = p.postfamilyID 
        inner join 
        PostFamilyTags as pt on p.postfamilyID = pt.postfamilyID 
        inner join --Tags
        Tags as t on pt.tagID = t.tagID 
        Where t.TagLevel = 1 and t.Tag = 'Electronic'
```

Can anyone help me make my first sql statment run faster?

Comment: You need to compare both queries without TOP 100 clause, that will give you a like to like comparison. In the first instance, query has to get all the millions of rows in the sub-query, while in the second instance it will break once 100 records are fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you aren't selecting any columns from either of the Tags tables, there's a different way you can write this:

```
Select Top(100)
  *
From (
  Select
    Row_Number() Over (Order By p.date Desc) as Num,
    m.postfamilymediaID,
    m.postfamilyID,
    m.postfamilymediatypeID as Type, 
    p.Title, 
    p.Date -- and the rest of the fields
  From
    PostFamilyMedia As m
      Inner Join 
    PostFamily As p On m.postfamilyID = p.postfamilyID 
  Where
    Exists (
      Select 
        'x'
      From 
        Tags As t 
          Inner Join
        PostFamilyTags As pt 
          On pt.tagID = t.tagID 
      Where
        t.TagLevel = 1 and
        t.Tag = 'Electronic' And
        p.postfamilyID = pt.postfamilyID
      )
  ) As a
Where
  Num >= (100 + 1) And Num <= (100 + 100);
```

In some very basic tests at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e073d/1, writing it this way will use a covering index on the date column, whereas the way you have it now doesn't. Whether this holds true at larger volumes (and whether it improves performance at all) needs testing.

Also, I assume `PostFamilyTags (PostFamilyID, TagID)` is unique. This sort of query is sensitive to the order you define a unique index in. The easiest way to find out which is best is to create both and see what the optimizer picks. It looks like `TagID, PostFamilyID` works best for small volumes.

If`Tags (TagLevel, Tag)` is unique, you could potentially read the unique TagID in a separate query, and then remove Tags from the main query. As Tags is likely to be small relative to the other tables, I wouldn't expect this to have much effect.

```
Declare @TagID int
Select
  @TagID = TagID
From
  Tags
Where
  TagLevel = 1 And
  Tag = 'Electronic'

Select Top(100)
  *
From (
  Select
    Row_Number() Over (Order By p.date Desc) as Num,
    m.postfamilymediaID,
    m.postfamilyID,
    m.postfamilymediatypeID as Type, 
    p.Title, 
    p.Date -- and the rest of the fields...
  From
    PostFamilyMedia As m
      Inner Join 
    PostFamily As p On m.postfamilyID = p.postfamilyID 
  Where
    Exists (
      Select 
        'x'
      From 
        PostFamilyTags As pt 
      Where
        p.postfamilyID = pt.postfamilyID And
        pt.TagID = @TagID
      )
  ) As a
Where
  Num >= (100 + 1) And Num <= (100 + 100);
```

As you're selecting all the `PostFamilyMedia` for each matching `PostFamily` you may get a speed up by clustering the first table on `PostFamilyID, PostFamilyMediaID` instead of its primary key. The second column is included to make it unique. SQL Server will add a hidden uniquifier value to a non-unique clustered index. The trade off is that if another part of your app selects individual records, it will be slightly slower. You can use another covering index to get both fast, at the cost of making inserts and updates slower.

Comment: Laurence, you are awesome! I knew my statement was lacking efficiency, and this rewrite seems to be working great...

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be what you consider "fast" versus "slow".  When a query might be returning millions of rows, often the time to first row seems is used as the length of the query.  However, you need to consider time to last row.

By adding the `row_number` function in, SQL needs to generate the entire result set, before it returns any rows.  It looks slower, but it is not really slower when measure to time-for-whole-result set (just a little because of the `row_number()`).

You might be able to speed this by doing the `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
from (select row_number() order by pdate) . . .
      from PostFamily p
     )
```

And then including the condition in the `on` clause.

Judicious use of indexing might help.  Do you have the pdate in an index on the table?  However, I'm not sure this would help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly; my approach to make the first query faster would be to index the table.column(order): `**PostFamily.date  DESC**`

The reason I say this is that it looks like you need to page your data (based on [Num]). As people have pointed out, the `ROW_NUMBER()` operation requires all qualifying rows to be read. But, they don't only need to be read, they need to be **sorted** as well. Sorting is very expensive, especially on large datasets. I'm hoping the index as I've described it will assist with this.

To explain the difference in the two queries, I can offer an analogy. Given the following list:

```
Mike
Susan
Andrew
Felicity
George
Laura
Ben
Robert
Julia
Jim
Kath
```

1. Give me the top 3 names
2. Give me the top 3 names by reverse alphabetic order

Which of these 2 tasks would cost you more work?

Comment: Thx for the breakdown, this helped.